# How to copy extra large values to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have a table with a huge cell values. These values are truncated to 100 symbols to make table lightweight and fast. On cell hover I show a CopyButton.
On CopyButton click i'm calling function copyToClipboard and passing cell value there.

During copying a value bigger than 1MB browser freezes for a minute and finally value in my clipboard doesn't change.

```
const copyToClipboard = text => {
    const textField = document.createElement('textarea')
    textField.innerText = text
    document.body.appendChild(textField)
    textField.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    textField.remove()
}
```

*Is there any clipboard solution that can operate with huge values?*

Answer (score 0):

**My workaround:**

In case when value is bigger than 150k symbols I throw a file to the users browser. Refer `downloadTextDocument` function.

```
const downloadTextDocument = (documentValue, filename) => {
    const blob = new File([documentValue], filename, { type: 'text/plain' })
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    download(downloadUrl, filename);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); // cleanup
}

const download = (url, filename) => {
    const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    tempLink.href = url;
    tempLink.setAttribute('download', filename)
    document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
    tempLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
}
```