# Javascript: Convert an array to CSV format and copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm trying to convert an array to lines that can be pasted in an excel CSV file. In the code below, I'm able to format the array content as I want it to be (at //return csvFile; line). Just after that I'm trying to create a hidden input, add the content of csvFile to it, select the text in the element and copy, but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
var array = [
    [0,1,1,0],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [0,1,1,0]
];
var string = copyCsv(array);
console.log(string);

function copyCsv(rows) {
    var processRow = function (row) {
        var finalVal = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            var innerValue = row[j] === null ? '' : row[j].toString();
            if (row[j] instanceof Date) {
                innerValue = row[j].toLocaleString();
            };
            var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
            if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
                result = '"' + result + '"';
            if (j > 0)
                finalVal += ',';
            finalVal += result;
        }
        return finalVal + '\n';
    };

    var csvFile = "\ufeff"+'';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
    }
    //return csvFile;
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    csvFile.append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

You can find my JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/464368/

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Creek Barbara, can you be more specific? What is not working in your code - content not getting formatted in CSV format or content not getting copied?

Comment: You cannot save a file to the Server with Client Side JavaScript, if that's what you intend.

Comment: As I said in my question the array is well formatted, It's when I try to copy it that it's not working.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm not trying to save a file. I'm trying to copy a string. My bad, bad naming of my variables, I'm reusing the same code that I used to save the CSV file.

Comment: Check your console. You have a lot of Type&Reference errors. [Once fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/koxL5fgz/), you'll face the issue that `execCommand('cut'/'copy')` must be initiated by a user gesture (so only the one from button click will work) Depending on the size of the data you are trying to generate you may also fall in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774820/copying-to-clipboard-with-document-execcommandcopy-fails-with-big-texts/44837372#44837372).

Comment: Hi Creek Barbara, the problem is that we cannot select a hidden HTML element. using a non hidden input (using your strategy) works https://jsfiddle.net/t8raz47c/5/

Comment: @D.Seah Cool, it works, Why it doesn't work when I move the Javascript to the javascript window instead of in script tag?

Comment: @Creek Barbara, can you tell me what csvFile.append($temp) is about? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.select()` need to be done on an element appended in DOM for the `execCommand()` to copy it.

Additionnally, modern browsers do not allow a copy to clipboard without a user click to trigger it.

I used a textarea element, since there is multiple lines....

This works:

```js
console.clear();
var array = [
  [0,1,1,0],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,1,0]
];

// A button to trigger the copy action.
$("#copy").on("click",function(){
  var string = copyCsv(array);
  console.log(string);
});

function copyCsv(rows) {
  var processRow = function (row) {
    var finalVal = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      var innerValue = row[j] === null ? '' : row[j].toString();
      if (row[j] instanceof Date) {
        innerValue = row[j].toLocaleString();
      };
      var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
      if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
        result = '"' + result + '"';
      if (j > 0)
        finalVal += ',';
      finalVal += result;
    }
    return finalVal + '\n';
  };

  var csvFile = "\ufeff"+'';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
  }
  console.log(csvFile);

  //return csvFile;
  var $temp = $("<textarea id='temp'>").text(csvFile);
  $("body").append($temp)
  $("#temp").select();
  var result = document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#temp").remove();
  return result?"Copied to clipboard":"Clipboard failed...";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="copy">Copy</button>
```

This doesn't:

```js
console.clear();
var array = [
  [0,1,1,0],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,1,0]
];

var string = copyCsv(array);
console.log(string);

function copyCsv(rows) {
  var processRow = function (row) {
    var finalVal = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      var innerValue = row[j] === null ? '' : row[j].toString();
      if (row[j] instanceof Date) {
        innerValue = row[j].toLocaleString();
      };
      var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
      if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
        result = '"' + result + '"';
      if (j > 0)
        finalVal += ',';
      finalVal += result;
    }
    return finalVal + '\n';
  };

  var csvFile = "\ufeff"+'';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
  }
  console.log(csvFile);

  //return csvFile;
  var $temp = $("<textarea id='temp'>").text(csvFile);
  $("body").append($temp)
  $("#temp").select();
  var result = document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#temp").remove();
  return result?"Copied to clipboard":"Clipboard failed...";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but I've a hard time understanding the "The .select() need to be done on an element appended in DOM for the execCommand() to copy it", sorry I'm a beginner. What was I doing wrong? expect the input instead of the text area.

Comment: In fact, the first atempt to copy take what is in my existing textarea. I've to click the button twice to copy the right information

Comment: The text to copy has to be focussed... Or highlighted by the `.select()`. If it only is a jQuery object not appended to DOM... The copy fails while it stranglely returns a true ... But from my tests in Chrome, it fails.

Comment: It's not really clear for me, but my main problem now is that I've to click 2 times on the button to copy the content, What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know about the 2 clicks... In the snippet here, it only takes 1.

Comment: I have made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GBWENL?editors=0010), if you want to play with it...

Comment: Yes, it works in your example but when I integrate it to my code I've to click the button twice to have the content copied to the clipboard, Look at the other comments and answers for user-gesture. I don't understand that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176534/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-creek-barbara).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. You want to add your CSV format into an input Hidden field.

I have modified your code a little

```
function copyCsv(rows) {
        var processRow = function (row) {
            var finalVal = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                var innerValue = row[j] === null ? '' : row[j].toString();
                if (row[j] instanceof Date) {
                    innerValue = row[j].toLocaleString();
                };
                var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
                if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
                    result = '"' + result + '"';
                if (j > 0)
                    finalVal += ',';
                finalVal += result;
            }
            return finalVal + '\n';
        };

        var csvFile = "\ufeff"+'';
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
        }
        //return csvFile;
        console.log(csvFile);

       var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      x.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      x.setAttribute("id", "myHiddenData");
      document.body.appendChild(x);
      document.getElementById("myHiddenData").value = csvFile;

        document.execCommand("copy");

        var copyText = document.getElementById("myHiddenData");

    document.execCommand("copy");

    copyText.select();

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);

  }
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/464410/)

Comment: My main goal is to copy the content of csvFile to clipboard. Thank you for your help but the code is returning this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: copyCsv is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Comment: @CreekBarbara this is because jsfiddle is set to wrap your js in an onload function and that you did attach the click handler as onclick attribute=> it is searching for window.copyCsv which doesn't exists. Setting your fiddle option to *no wrap in body*  will make this code work on click (but it won't at first call because execCommand requires an user-gesture)

Comment: What do you mean by user-gesture? I've already used it in another script and it worked from the first time. The user has to interact with the page first before trying to copy the text by clicking on the button. I've tried your updated code and it doesn't copy the content. Thank you again for your help.